# How do I upload images from node/express REST API to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, google-cloud-storage, backend

I'm building a REST API with node/express/mongoDB deployed on Netlify functions (the DB is straight from MongoDB Atlas). What I'd like to do is to create an API route that allows an image to be uploaded as one of the fields in a POST request. Express will then upload this file to Google Cloud Storage, get the newly uploaded image url, and store this url as one of the document field in the database.

One of the options that have crossed my mind is to use `multer`. As it is deployed as a serverless functions, Express doesn't have access to any storage. That means I can't store the image locally with `multer`, and saving it in the memory would cause too many potential problems (the images are videogame screenshots, so they're pretty huge). Right now, this is a no-go, or at least, not my ideal option.

The most ideal approach I think, is to somehow directly upload this file straight to Google Cloud Storage from the API route handling. [This was achieved by Ben Awad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGSzMfKBV9Q), but I understood very very little of his codes (`resolvers`? `express.static()`? `Mutation`?). It was practically me pulling out my hair at every line.

I have no idea how to access a file being uploaded from a POST request without `multer`, let alone uploading it straight to GCS.

How should I go about handling this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [NodeJS GCP storage client](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage) could help

In the Github readme page there are several samples of how to do stuff with node and GCP storage.

[Here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/uploadFile.js) you can find the below upload example

```
    function main(bucketName = 'my-bucket', filename = './local/path/to/file.txt') {
      // [START storage_upload_file]
      /**
       * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
       */
      // const bucketName = 'Name of a bucket, e.g. my-bucket';
      // const filename = 'Local file to upload, e.g. ./local/path/to/file.txt';

      // Imports the Google Cloud client library
      const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

      // Creates a client
      const storage = new Storage();

      async function uploadFile() {
        // Uploads a local file to the bucket
        await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename, {
          // Support for HTTP requests made with `Accept-Encoding: gzip`
          gzip: true,
          // By setting the option `destination`, you can change the name of the
          // object you are uploading to a bucket.
          metadata: {
            // Enable long-lived HTTP caching headers
            // Use only if the contents of the file will never change
            // (If the contents will change, use cacheControl: 'no-cache')
            cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
          },
        });

        console.log(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
      }

      uploadFile().catch(console.error);
      // [END storage_upload_file]
    }

    main(...process.argv.slice(2));
```